# SSL Protocol Error on localhost when redirecting after using fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, localhost

```
GET https://localhost:8080/contact net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I don't get this error on the live site that is secured by HTTPS (but am working on fixing another bug). I've read countless StackOverflow posts about this but couldn't find anything to get it to work on localhost. I prefer not to have to go through the hassle of creating a self-signed certificate for localhost, if possible.

I have a contact form whose input values I'm POSTing to the backend via the fetch API in client-side JS (it didn't have this error when I did it through the HTML form action attribute but due to spam mail I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHA v3, which involves generating a token client-side and sending it to the server to be validated). The Express backend will process the information, then redirect to /contact. The processing of the data is all going smoothly and the submissions are being emailed to me and logged into the database, but the page doesn't redirect as it should at the end of the processing. I've found that for some reason it's trying to redirect to https://localhost instead of http://localhost, but I'm not quite sure why that's the case, as it worked on localhost prior to submitting to the backend with fetch instead of inside the form.

The redirect is just: `res.redirect('/contact');`

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: backend should get correct protocol from your request, then use it for redirect or you can manually change protocol in browser to `http`

Comment: @Mike yeah when posting it uses the right protocol (http) so that works, but when redirecting via express, it uses https for some reason (it didn't before making the changes i mentioned in the post). i'm using a relative, not absolute, path: `res.redirect('/contact');`

Comment: you server may use some middleware to redirect to `https` protocol, try to research in code

Comment: just checked, there's no middleware that should do that. it worked fine before adding the recaptcha verification process, and i didn't add any middleware for that other than changing express.urlencoded to express.json bc the client js sends the data in json

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.